# MySQL Invoice numbers range with count

Tags: mysql

Firstly I want this to be purely done with MySQL query.

I have a series of Invoice numbers

```
invoice_number
INV001
INV002
INV003
INV004
INV005
001
002
003
006
007
009
010
INVOICE333
INVOICE334
INVOICE335
INVOICE337
INVOICE338
INVOICE339
001INV
002INV
005INV
009INV
```

I want to output something like this

```
from_invoice_no    to_invoice_no    total_invoices
INV001             INV005           5
001                010              7
INVOICE333         INVOICE339       6
001INV             009INV           4
```

The invoice number pattern cannot be fixed. They can change in future

Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will there be always two parts in an invoice number, one part being consecutive digits and the other part being consecutive non-digits, or could an invoice number be something like `001INV003FOO1234BAR`?

Comment: Yes, something like `PRCMMU1718/00057`, `PRCMMU1718/00058`, `AQW1025`, `AQW1028`, `AQW1030`, `1258POC`, `1259POC`...

Comment: Are you allowed (i.e. do you have the privilege) to add two additional columns to that table, or to create a new table?

Answer (score 0):

I will first show a general idea how to solve this problem and provide some code which will be ugly, but easily understandable. Then I'll explain what the issues are and how to remedy them.

**STEP 1: Deriving the grouping criterion**

For the first step, I assume you have the right (privilege) to create an additional column in your table. Let us name it `invoice_text`. Now, the general idea is to remove all digits from the invoice number so that only the "text pattern" remains. Then we can group by the text pattern.

Assuming that you have already created the column mentioned above, you could do the following:

```
UPDATE Invoices SET invoice_text = REPLACE(invoice_number, '0', '');
UPDATE Invoices SET invoice_text = REPLACE(invoice_text, '1', '');
UPDATE Invoices SET invoice_text = REPLACE(invoice_text, '2', '');
...
UPDATE Invoices SET invoice_text = REPLACE(invoice_text, '9', '');
```

After having done that, you will have the pure text pattern without digits in `invoice_text` and can use that for grouping:

```
SELECT COUNT(invoice_number) AS total_invoices FROM Invoices
  GROUP BY invoice_text
```

This is nice, but it is not yet what you wanted. It does not show the first and last invoice number for each group.

**STEP 2: Deriving the first and last invoice for each group**

For this step, create one more column in your table. Let us name it `invoice_digits`. As the name implies, it is meant to take only the pure invoice number without the "pattern text".

Assuming you have that column, you could do the following:

```
UPDATE Invoices SET invoice_digits = REPLACE(invoice_number, 'A', '');
UPDATE Invoices SET invoice_digits = REPLACE(invoice_digits, 'B', '');
UPDATE Invoices SET invoice_digits = REPLACE(invoice_digits, 'C', '');
...
UPDATE Invoices SET invoice_digits = REPLACE(invoice_digits, 'Z', '');
```

Now, you can use that column to get the minimum and maximum invoice number (without "pattern text"):

```
SELECT
  MIN(invoice_digits) AS from_invoice_no,
  MAX(invoice_digits) AS to_invoice_no,
  COUNT(invoice_number) AS total_invoices
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY invoice_text
```

**Problems and how to solve them**

**1)** According to your question, you want to get the minimum and maximum *full invoice number text*. The solution above will show only the minimum and maximum *invoice number text without the text parts*, i.e. only the digits.

We could remedy this by doing a further `JOIN`, but since I can very well imagine that you won't insist on this :-), and since it won't make the general idea more clear, I am leaving this to you. If you are interested, let us know.

**2)** It might be difficult to decide what a digit (i.e. what the actual invoice *number*) is. For example, if you have invoice numbers like `INV001`, `INV002`, this will be no problem, but what if you have `INV001/001`, `INV001/002`, `INV002/003` and so on? In this example, my code would would yield `001001`, `001002`, `002003` as actual invoice numbers and use that to decide what the minimum and maximum numbers are.

This might not be what you want to do in that case. The only way around this is that you thoroughly think about what you should consider a digit and what not, and to adapt my code accordingly.

**3)** My code currently uses string comparisons to get the minimum and maximum invoice numbers. This may yield other results than comparing the values as numbers. If you are wondering what that means: Compare `'19'` to `'9'` as string, and compare `19` to `9` as number.

If this is a problem, then use MySQL's `CAST` to convert the text to a number before feeding it to `MAX` or `MIN`. But please be aware that this has its own caveats:

If you have very long invoice numbers with so many digits that they don't fit into MySQL's numeric data types, this method will fail. It will also fail if you have defined a character like `/` to be digits (due to the issues described in 2)) since MySQL can't convert this into a number.

Instead of converting to numbers, you can also pad the values in `invoice_digits` with leading zeroes, for example using MySQL's `LPAD` function. This will avoid the problems described above and sort the numbers as expected, even if they include non-digits like `/`, but you will have to know the maximum length of the digit string in advance.

**4)** The code is ugly! Do you really have to remove all possible characters from `A` to `Z` one by one by doing `UPDATE` statements to get the digit string?

Actually, it is even worse. I just have *assumed* that you only have the "text characters" `A` to `Z` in your invoices. But there could be any character Unicode defines: Russian or Chinese ones, special characters, in other words: thousands of different characters.

Unfortunately, AFAIK, MySQL still does not provide a REGEX-REPLACE function. I don't see any chance to get this problem solved unless you extend MySQL with an appropriate UDF (user defined function). There are some cool guys out there who have recognized the problem and have added such functions to MySQL. Since recommending libraries seems to be discouraged on SO, just google for "mysql regex replace".

When having extended MySQL that way, you can replace the ugly bunch of `UPDATE` statements which remove the digits / the text from the invoice number by a single one (using a REGEX, you can replace all digits or all non-digits at once).

For the sake of completeness, you could avoid the many `UPDATE` statements by doing `UPDATE ... SET ... = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(...)))` and thus applying all updates with one statement. But this is even more ugly and error prone, so if you are serious about your problem, you'll really have to extend MySQL by a REGEX-REPLACE.

**5)** The solution will only work if you have the privilege to create new columns in the table.

This is true for the solution as-is. But I have chosen to go that way solely because it makes the general idea clear and understandable. Instead of adding columns to your original table, you could also create a new table where you store the pure text / digits (this table might be a temporary one).

Furthermore, since MySQL supports grouping by computed values, you don't need additional columns / tables at all. You should decide by yourself what is the best way to go.

Comment: As you mentioned in point 2, that is exactly my case. The prefix and suffix can be alphanumeric followed by incremental numbers. The invoice patterns are not defined in the system. I will have to find some other way to do this, may be via PHP

Comment: You won't have a chance to solve this by software as long as there is no rule what belongs to the pattern and what to the actual number. If I got your comment right, even the digits could be part of the pattern. Thus, for example, if you have `INV001` and `INV002`, then you can't even tell if the pattern is `INV00` and the actual numbers are `1` and `2`, or if the pattern is `INV0` and the actual numbers are `01` and `02`, or if the pattern is `INV` and the actual number are `001` and `002`.